# Cant open chrome profile with selenium

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I'm making a Whatsapp bot, but is doesn't let me open Whatssapp web without scanning the QR code. I have seen other questions on Stackoverflow with the same problem. It says that you need to open your chrome profile with chrome.

I have already tried to update Selenium, Pip, Pycharm etc, but it still doesn't work. Also, tried it with user-data-dir. But still nothing.

With chrome://version you can find the profile path of your chrome profile i copied the path and add it as an argument but still can't open my chrome profile with Selenium.

Also, made a second chrome profile and stored the folder somewhere else on my PC but that also doesn't work. Tried i lot of things but nothing seems to work, anybody else got these problems.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("/Users/maxbenenn/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome")
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 2")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("/Users/maxbenenn/Desktop/chromedriver"), options = options)
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Mention your profile path like below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\<User>\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")  #if you want to use default profile, otherwise mention that specific profile's dir name here

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("/Users/maxbenenn/Desktop/chromedriver"), options = options)
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
```

Comment: Then is still opens chrome without profile and i get a fault code "DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/maxbenenn/Desktop/chromedriver")"

Comment: Use the below line from my code:  

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("/Users/maxbenenn/Desktop/chromedriver"), options = options).  

and import:

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

executable_path is deprecated, so you have to include service.

Comment: Updated the import in my code, check it.

Comment: Its still opening the automated browser, i checked the profile path of the browser and its "/private/var/folders/48/jrd383_560x95rfr0wbzqw6c0000gn/T/.com.google.Chrome.V4sW3i/Profile 1". So its opening Profile 1 but not logging in to whatsapp. I tried logging in with the QR code in the browser and then its logging normally. But when I close the window and open it again with Pycharm its till not logged in. Also, tried it with a second profile in still doesn't log in. But after chancing the code the fault code is gone, thank you for that. (Also updated the code so you can see what is have)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/820

Here is the solution to your problem. Use `undetected_chromedriver` (powered by selenium) to sign in to google profile.